# Switch statement usage - C

Tags: c, winapi, events, switch-statement

I have a thread function on Process B that contains a switch to perform certain operations based on the results of an event sent from Process A, these are stored as two elements in an array.

I set the first element to the event which signals when Process A has data to send and I have the second element set to the event which indicates when Process A has closed.

I have began to implement the functionality for the switch statement but I'm not getting the results as I expect.

Consider the following:

```
//Thread function
        DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(LPVOID passedHandle)
        {    
            for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                ghEvents[i] = OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, TEXT("Global\\ProducerEvents"));
                if(ghEvents[i] == NULL)
                {
                    getlasterror = GetLastError();
                }
            }
            dwProducerEventResult = WaitForMultipleObjects(
                2,
                ghEvents,
                FALSE,
                INFINITE);

        switch (dwProducerEventResult) 
        {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0: 
            {
                //Producer sent data
                //unpackedHandle = *((HWND*)passedHandle);

                MessageBox(NULL,L"Test",L"Test",MB_OK);
                break;
            }
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
            {
                //Producer closed
                ExitProcess(1);
                break;
            }
        default: 
            return;
        }

}
```

As you can see if the event in the first array is signalled Process B should display a simple message box, if the second array is signalled the application should close.

When I actually close Process A, Process B displays the message box instead.

If I leave the first case blank (Do nothing) both applications close as they should.

Furthermore Process B sends data an error is thrown (When I comment out the unpacking):

[image: Error Image]

Have I implemented my switch statement incorrectly? I though I handled the unpacking of the HWND correctly too, any suggestions?

Thanks for your time.

**Edit:**

The example I'm following: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686915(v=VS.85).aspx)

Event creation in Process A:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
            { 
                ghEvents[i] = CreateEvent( 
                    NULL,   // default security attributes
                    TRUE,  // auto-reset event object
                    FALSE,  // initial state is nonsignaled
                    TEXT("Global\\ProducerEvents"));  // unnamed object

                if (ghEvents[i] == NULL) 
                { 
                    printf("CreateEvent error: %d\n", GetLastError() ); 
                    ExitProcess(0); 
                } 
        }
```

Comment: Can you reformat the code to remove all the extraneous white space and correct (make consistent) the indentation? It's really hard to read at the moment.

Comment: Wow, good lucking maintaining that.

Comment: @Michael: The code isn't designed to be maintained as it will only ever loop through twice, furthermore the formatting/white space is what I'm accustomed too, I don't like things clumped together. White space is ignored at compile time anyway so there's no performance impact.

Comment: @Jamie, I don't think you understand the meaning of "maintain".... maintaining code means having you or other developers continue to support and evolve your code. Using a switch statement instead of looking up a class or function pointer in a table and dispatching to a virtual function of that class or dispatching to that function, really is quite a mess, and when the switch statement gets larger, it is really harder to effectively debug and extend. I don't know where your comment about formatting or whitespace is coming from, 'cause I wasn't talking about that at all.

Comment: @Michael, I don't think you understood what I put. I know exactly what maintaining means, you seemed to assume that my code was going to be maintained in the first place when in fact it's for an assignment with only one purpose, it's the only purpose it will ever have. It will never been maintained by another developer and it will never be improved. Heck, I'll redo it in my own time if I decide to but for this purpose, it's perfectly fine. I'm well accustomed to developing software that can be maintained but it's not practical in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you opening the same event twice?

```
ghEvents[i] = OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, TEXT("Global\\ProducerEvents"));
```

Shouldn't there be two different events?

This is consistent with the behavior you are reporting

> When I actually close Process A,
>   Process B displays the message box
>   instead.

Because when you close process A the same event is signalled that enters the switch as `WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0`

To sum up, create two different events - one for when process A is closing and the other to signal the message box to be shown.

**The code below will only work for i <= 0 <= 9** But the main point is that the cycle iteration must create an event with a different name.

Process A:

```
LPTSTR eventName[] = _T("Global\\ProducerEventi");
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
{ 
    eventName[20] = '0' - i; // this will change last i character with '0' or '1'
    ghEvents[i] = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, eventName);
 ...
```

Process B:

```
LPTSTR eventName[] = _T("Global\\ProducerEventi");
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    eventName[20] = '0' - i; // this will change last i character with '0' or '1'
    ghEvents[i] = OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, eventName);
    ...
```

Comment: There is, as I mentioned I have an array of events. I've seen in the MSDN documentation that it can be done with an array of events and i've tried to stay faithful to their implementation.

Comment: You have an array of events, true. Each position holds the same event also true. So when in process A you signal either event (always the same) you always end up in `WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0`.

Comment: I don't understand, I set each events individually in Process A for example, SetEvent(ghEvents[0]);.

Comment: Events are identified by name. You gave the same name to both so, in practice, they are the same when seen by process B. Try appending an index - should be easy as you could use `for` index variable `i`.

Comment: I've tried following the same technique in the MSDN article, I've added the link to it. I didn't realise mine was different.

Comment: They are using a single event.

Comment: Changed to code to reflect my previous comments and notes from answer.

Comment: @smink: it looks a bit weird... Obviously, it does the job in the current situation, but it will not work for more than 10 events.

Comment: @Jamie: the MSDN example actually creates a single (named) event and several threads - and the wait is done on the threads, not the event.

Comment: @smink: Could you explain your snippet in a little bit more detail? I'm new to using events.

Comment: @RaphaelSP, you are right. The code will work for i <= 0 <= 9. But for the trivial example posted it works. Nevertheless the emphasized part is that the event name should change for each for iteration. Use _stprintf function for example.

Answer (score 1):

it is not about case/switch. you are trying to dereference invalid pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to dereference a HWND, hence the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're calling `ThreadFunc` like this:

```
ThreadFunc(hwndSomeWindow);
```

In which case, the cast should be:

```
unpackedHandle = (HWND) passedHandle;
```

Your code would have been right if the call were like this:

```
ThreadFunc(&hwndSomeWindow);
```